# How to mock #available with Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Swift class which computes something just for iOS 11. This means that I have the following check:

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    //do magic
}
```

I'm wondering how I can mock `#available` for my unit tests. I would like to test:

1. If `#available` is called with the right parameters
2. The code inside the if statement. For it, I would like having a way to force the result of the statement of `if #available(iOS 11, *)`.

**Update:**

Since I had these difficulties, I changed approached and moved to:

```
let result = device.systemVersion.compare("11", options: .numeric)
return result == .orderedSame || result == .orderedDescending
```

Any answers to the problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related [Testing API availability with Swift2.0](https://sharpfivesoftware.com/2015/09/02/testing-api-availability-with-swift-2-0/)

Comment: Hey @DávidPásztor, thank you for the article. Maybe I misunderstood the article, but with this approach I wouldn't able to test my two points, would I ?  And my SUT contains that if statement. Even if I use a strategy design pattern I wouldn't still able to test the two points I mentioned. If I'm wrong, feel free to add an answer please.

Comment: If I got the last hint in the article correctly, setting the build target for a specific iOS version should let you execute the `#available` statements in your tests. I haven't tested it though, so cannot vouch for its correctness.

Comment: Any updates on the above? Me too facing the same.

Comment: Hi @Shyam, I had to change approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46511901/5109911

Comment: I didnt get how it will be helpful in code coverage?Even if you change the approach how to mock the device version?Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Shyam you can mock `UIDevice` creating a protocol to abstract it and let `UIDevice` implement it with an extension (as usual way to mock an Apple's framework object)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I had these difficulties, I changed approached and moved to:

```
let result = device.systemVersion.compare("11", options: .numeric)
return result == .orderedSame || result == .orderedDescending
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the check to a function like this:

```
func isAvailable() -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

And then include this function in the production code, but mock it in tests.

Furthermore, you could add parameters to that function if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With this approach I wouldn't able to test if `#available` is called in production. I would need to mock the `#available` function itself. Unfortunately, I wasn't lucky in it.